# can we execute webservice from developer console

Tags: rest

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Merchandise/*')
global with sharing class MerchandiseManager {

    @HttpGet
    global static Merchandise__c getMerchandiseById() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;        
        String merchId = req.requestURI.substring(
                                  req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Merchandise__c result = 
                       [SELECT Name,Description__c,Price__c,Total_Inventory__c
                        FROM Merchandise__c 
                        WHERE Id = :merchId];
        return result;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static String createMerchandise(String name,
        String description, Decimal price, Double inventory) {
        Merchandise__c m = new Merchandise__c(
            Name=name,
            Description__c=description,
            Price__c=price,
            Total_Inventory__c=inventory);
        insert m;
        return m.Id;
    }
}
```

can we execute this class using instantiation in developer consoler.and how can call this web service from the other system,,please suggest me ,how to do,,,?!thanks in advance,iam a fresher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the developer console you just need to call the method . Something like

```
MerchandiseManager.getMerchandiseById()
```

And from an external service you need to make a rest request using endpoint

```
(baseUrl)/services/apexrest/Merchandise

https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/FieldCase?companyName=GenePoint
```

You can find more detailed information here

[Creating REST APIs using Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)

[Consuming Force.com SOAP and REST Web Services from .NET Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications)

Comment: what is this FieldCase,and ComapanyName.

Comment: @sahisfdc fieldcase is class name and ComapanyName is parameter name.

Comment: https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/FieldCase?companyName=GenePoint,,using this url,can i call my webservice from other orgs

Comment: @sahisfdc yes you can.

Comment: https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MerchandiseManager ?name=GenePoint,this is my url,not working for me.

Comment: @sahisfdc you also need to specify 3 other parameter and I hope you are making a proper request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45039/discussion-between-sahisfdc-and-tushar-sharma).

Comment: @TusharSharma please come to chat